# Best way to modify VBA Macros when rows or columns are inserted or deleted?

Tags: excel, vba

I have been working on developing excel vba based forms with my little knowledge. Once in six months, Client ask to change the structure of the forms, insert few fields, delete few fields, give inputs to incorporate few conditions/logics. This is repeated every six months. Also when developing forms for current, they keep changing their inputs. It is really painful to go and edit the forms and macro at the backend which refer each cell value of the specific field/table. I have to do this for each macro present in the form(including Userform, Module, code behind sheets). Input files keep changing and non standard. Please suggest me what is the best way to do the changes in macro, Like formula in excel change automatically when you insert or delete rows or columns, move formula to another cell.

Comment: Name the ranges?

Comment: ^^ Or use `.Find` to return columns/rows dynamically and work from there

Comment: Use looping over `Controls` of form dynamically so that when you add new boxes it can work automatically.

Comment: Best is to Name the ranges as Siddharth said. Then you need not worry about the whereabouts of the cells. They can be directly used using the names.

Comment: Thanks Siddharth Rout, for your answers. It helped me a lot by reducing my work.